# .htaccess redirect umlaut domain

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect, idn

I am trying to redirect requests from a umlaut domain to another domain.

My following code works with ANY other domain, but not umlaut:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?frankfurter-flöhe\.de/$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://kinderkultur-frankfurt.de/frankfurter-floehe-theaterprogramm.html [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

However, when I call the umlaut domain and then copy it from Google Chrome's address bar, I get this:

```
http://xn--frankfurter-flhe-zwb.de/
```

Although, if I use that obfuscated domain in my htaccess file instead of the "real" umlaut domain, it doesn't work either.

Does anybody have an idea how to match that domain?

Comment: "that obfuscated domain" is in [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) and is how internationalised domains are stored in DNS.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the NE flag, to prevent mod_rewrite from encoding the URL. For more information about NE: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?frankfurter-flöhe\.de/$ [NC,NE]
  RewriteRule ^ http://kinderkultur-frankfurt.de/frankfurter-floehe-theaterprogramm.html [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

If this doesn't work, try to use the HEX equivalent of umlaut, as suggested in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107375/umlauts-in-htaccess-redirects

Comment: I tried this already (as mentioned above) and it doesn't work.

Comment: I updated my answer to use the NE flag instead.

Comment: The NE flag results in an error 500

Comment: Did you add the space after NC, NE? That might cause the 500 error. I removed it from the answer. It might also be [NC] [NE] - Not really sure. I will run some tests later if you don't get it working.

Comment: The error appears with and without the space, as well as when only the NE flag is used.

Comment: And is it safe to assume that you've tried with: frankfurter-flh%C3%A4he\.de/$ without the NE tag?

Comment: The `NE` flag only applies to the `RewriteRule` directive in order to prevent the substitution (ie. the _target URL_) from being escaped when sending back a response. It does not apply to the `RewriteCond` directive (which is only concerned with pattern matching), hence the 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^frankfurter-flöhe.de$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.frankfurter-flöhe.de$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://kinderkultur-frankfurt.de/frankfurter-floehe-theaterprogramm.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You simply split up my condition into two conditions. My condition works perfectly well with other domain names but not with the umlaut domain. Splitting it up makes no difference.

Comment: Yes but I want to check if when splitting your conditions, it solves the problem, because redirection on frankfurter-flöhe.de works, but not www.frankfurter-flöhe.de redirection

Comment: Nope, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The UTF-8 URL with Umlaut needs to be converted into ACE encoding (ASCII Compatible Encoding).

You can use the following [online tool](https://www.verisign.com/en_US/channel-resources/domain-registry-products/idn/idn-conversion-tool/index.xhtml) to convert an international domain with Umlauts.

[www.frankfurter-flöhe.de](http://www.xn--frankfurter-flhe-zwb.de) becomes xn--frankfurter-flhe-zwb.de and this is what needs to be used in the htaccess redirect.